# Python regular expressions inside parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

I'm having some trouble when trying to some get some data from within parenthesis. Here's some sample code:

```
import re    
test_string = '123a (456b)'
regex_a = re.match(r'(?P<a>\d+)a', test_string)
regex_b = re.match(r'(?P<b>\d+)b', test_string)
print regex_a
print regex_b
```

I would have expected the two regex objects to come back with 123 and 456 respectively, but `regex_b` returns `None`. Here's a python fiddle showing it (not) working: http://pythonfiddle.com/regex-in-parenthesis

I also tried this in Pythex too ([here's a link](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3FP%3Cb%3E%5Cd%2B)b&test_string=(456b)&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)), but in that environment it works!

I'm scratching my head as to what's going on, any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated. I'm using python 2.6 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try to replace `(` with `\(` and `)` with `\)`.

Comment: `match` starts at the beginning of the string.  Use `search` instead.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and dozens if not hundreds of other questions on this site.

Comment: Appreciated it was in the documentation, but when I've used .match() in the past and not come across this, it's not unreasonable for me to question the regex I'd written, not the function I was using. However, every day's a school day, and it's not a mistake I'll be making again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.match()` only matches from the beginning of the string. Try `re.search()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the number within parenthesis you can use the following regex :

```
\((\d+).*\)
```

*Note* that you need to escape the parenthesis and use capture grouping for your digit combination (`\d+`),also *Note* that `re.match` [checks for a match only at the beginning of the string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match),instead you need to use `re.search` :

```
>>> re.search(r'\((\d+).*\)',test_string).group(1)
'456'
```

And if you want to find all numbers you can use `re.findall` :

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+',test_string)
['123', '456']
```

Comment: The creator doesn't want to escape the parenthesis but uses them to create groups to later retrieve the values.

Comment: @syntonym Thanks for explain ;), it just was an answer!